# Can I get a lightsaber in Battlefront?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront

In Star Wars: Battlefront I've always been in situations where I wished I had a lightsaber to hack at some enemy CPUs. I was just wondering If there was a glitch or a weird Easter egg to have the legendary laser sword. I read a cheat code sheet and I found what I was looking for, but it didn't work for my PS2.

Can anyone give me some direction on how I could get a lightsaber?

Comment: Cheat: kill jaws to get big points on mos eisly

Comment: Tags can't have spaces in them, its normal :)

Comment: I suppose it's different from Battlefront 2 where the top player is given jedi?

Answer (score 3):

No, sorry.

I can't find any suggestion that a lightsaber was available, even in the form of a cheat, prior to Battlefront 2.

Comment: That's just sad... The original Battlefront 2 lets me be a Jedi.